# Protocol Buffers. Error in generated header file via proto-c. Invalid conversion

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, debian-stretch

In my project `C/C++` I must using Protocol Buffer with `protoc` file. After generated code from file `switch.proto` using below tool

```
protoc-c -I="./proto/" --c_out="./protobuf-c" proto/*.pro
```

I get files. Header  `switch.pb-c.h` and source file `switch.pb-c.c`. The problem is in generated code in header file which give me error

---

```
error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'SwitchValue' {aka '_SwitchValue'} [-fpermissive]
         , 0,0 }
```

---

This error I found in code in header file each I shouldn't edit:

```
#define SWITCH_REPORT__INIT \
 { PROTOBUF_C_MESSAGE_INIT (&switch_report__descriptor) \
    , 0,0 }
```

---

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "metadata.proto";

message SwitchRequest {
  DeviceMetadata metadata = 1;
}

message SwitchResponse {}

message SwitchReport {
  SwitchValue value = 1;
}

enum SwitchValue {
  SWITCH_UNKNOWN = 0;
  SWITCH_ON = 1;
  SWITCH_OFF = 2;
}
```

For now I don't know how it solve.
One suspect one thing, is to old gcc compiler 8.3.0. If I'm right, I also will be must upgrade my system (actualy Debian 9.8) and this is will be not good.

Comment: `protoc-c` is not a google's protobuf compiler. Unlikely it's a well-known tool for SO users. Report a bug https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c/issues. You tag your question with C++, why do you use `protoc-c`?

Comment: Before I try use just protoc and I get error. This tool was be used for my fellow as well in docker. So I also it installed local and try use. So what compiler I should be use ? About tag, ok my mistake. I create this project in c++ that's why I give wrong tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'SwitchValue' {aka '_SwitchValue'} [-fpermissive]
> , 0,0 }

The header file is trying to initialize an `enum` type with a value of `0`. This is valid thing to do in C, but not allowed by default in C++.

If you are using C++ in your project, you should probably use Google's official C++ protobuf library.

But if for some reason you need to use the protobuf-c library in a C++ project, add `-fpermissive` to the compilation options. This will allow the code to compile, but it will also disable some other useful compiler errors.

Comment: It works. I used -fpermissive flag only in CMakeLists for this package. thx